# problem met when checking collision between circle and polygon using SAT

Tags: c, graphics, game-development

I try to use SAT to check collision between circle and polygon, it works well when the circle is near the edges (of polygon), however when circle is closet to the corners (of polygon), it is push inside, and outside after that.

under this it failed

[image]

but under such cases it works well

[image]

How to solve this?

the algorithm looks like this:

```
double mtv = DBL_MAX; // minimum translation vector
Vector2 minAxis;
foreach(Edge e in p.Edges)
{
    var axis = e.normal;
    var circleInterval = ProjectInterval(c, axis);
    var polygonInterval = ProjectInterval(p, axis);
    float overlap = OverlapIntervals(circleInterval, polygonInterval);
    if(overlap < 0)
    {
        //the intervals overlap if it returns a positive number
        return -1.0f;
    }

    if(overlap < mtv)
    {
        mtv = overlap;
        minAxis = e.normal;
    }
}
```

and my code is here:

```
static AS_UNUSED inline AS_Bool AS_SAT_test_polygon_circle(AS_Polygon *poly, AS_Circle *circle, AS_Result *result) { 

AS_Vector *axis_normed = AS_vector_create(0, 0);
if (result) {
    result->is_overlapping = AS_TRUE;
    result->shape_a = poly;
    result->shape_b = circle;
    result->type_a = AS_POLYGON;
    result->type_b = AS_CIRCLE;
}

for (int i = 0; i < array_len(poly->coords); i++) {
    AS_Vector *coord1 =poly->coords[i];
    AS_Vector *coord2 = poly->coords[i + 1 >= array_len(poly->coords) ? 0 : i + 1];
    axis_normed->x = coord1->x - coord2->x;
    axis_normed->y = coord1->y - coord2->y;

    AS_vector_perp(axis_normed);
    AS_vector_norm(axis_normed);

    double min1 = DBL_MAX, max1 = -DBL_MAX;
    double dot_product;
    for (int j = 0; j < array_len(poly->coords); j++) {
        dot_product = AS_vector_dot(poly->coords[j], axis_normed);
        if (dot_product > max1) max1 = dot_product;
        if (dot_product < min1) min1 = dot_product;
    }

    double b = AS_vector_dot(circle->position, axis_normed);
    double a = b - circle->radius, c = b + circle->radius;
    double min2, max2;
    min2 = a < b ? a : b;
    min2 = min2 < c ? min2 : c;
    max2 = a > b ? a : b;
    max2 = max2 > c ? max2 : c;

    if (result) {
        double overlap;
        if (min1 < min2) {
            result->a_in_b = AS_FALSE;
            if (max1 < min2) {
                result->is_overlapping = AS_FALSE;
                return AS_FALSE;
            } else if (max1 < max2) {
                overlap = max1 - min2;
            } else {
                double option1 = max1 - min2;
                double option2 = max2 - min1;
                overlap = option1 < option2 ? option1 : option2;
            }
        } else {
            result->b_in_a = AS_FALSE;
            if (max2 < min1) {
                result->is_overlapping = AS_FALSE;
                return AS_FALSE;
            } else if (max2 < max1) {
                overlap = max2 - min1;
            } else {
                double option1 = max2 - min1;
                double option2 = max1 - min2;
                overlap = option1 < option2 ? option1 : option2;
            }
        }

        if (overlap < result->overlap) {
            result->overlap = overlap;
            result->overlap_x = axis_normed->x;
            result->overlap_y = axis_normed->y;
        }
    } else {
        if (min1 > max2 || min2 > max1) {
            return AS_FALSE;
        }
    }
}
return AS_TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add add a check about closest point of the polygon, that will be okay.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).